# Shortcut for maximizing IE 8 windows?

Tags: internet-explorer-8

My IE pages never open at maximum and having to click the "Max" button on 60 windows is hand-weary.  Any shortcut to maximizing?  Also, if the computer crashes and I resume the session every window loads at non-maximun! And once in a while they open at maximum all the time.  Why does it change randomnly?

Windows 7 64-bit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Shortcut for maximising IE windows is the same as maximising any other window.

Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to get the window menu, then press <kbd>X</kbd> to maximise the window. Once you've pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>, you can also use other shortcuts: <kbd>R</kbd> restores them to non-maximized mode and <kbd>N</kbd> minimises, for example.

Not sure if this is super useful if you've got 60 windows to maximise, but it's faster than finding the maximize button and clicking it individually 60 times..

On a side note, a handy trick if you ever lose a window (e.g. it's offscreen) is the following: Press  <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> for window menu, press <kbd>M</kbd> to start moving the window, press any arrow key to make the mouse cursor jump to the title bar of the window, and then move the mouse around wildly to get the window back on screen :)

**Edit**: [Ampersand's answer](https://superuser.com/a/366223/88737) is simpler for anyone on Windows 7 or above.

Answer (score 3):

In Windows 7 a lot of window positioning controls have been mapped to Windows Key + Arrow.

<kbd>windows</kbd> + <kbd>up arrow</kbd> =
 Maximize the window. (Restore if already minimized)
<kbd>windows</kbd> + <kbd>down arrow</kbd> =
 Minimize the window. (Restore if already maximized)
<kbd>windows</kbd> + <kbd>left arrow</kbd> =
 Maximize the window to the left side of the screen.
<kbd>windows</kbd> + <kbd>right arrow</kbd> =
 Maximize the window to the right side of the screen.

You can find more by searching for "keyboard shortcuts" in Windows Help and Support.

Comment: +1 for the Windows key shortcuts which I completely forgot about. The `Winkey`+`Left` & +`Right` are possibly even better for tracking down windows (on win 7+ anyway)

Comment: Weird.  Win+UpArrow doesn't work for me.

Comment: Just Win + Up or all of them?

Also, thanks for putting in the keyboard formatting, Simon.

Answer (score 0):

It is a standard behavior in Windows that new windows which do not specifically set their own size are created with a default size and at a default position of a one titlebar’s height down and to the right of the last window that was created (until a point, then it loops back to the top-left of the screen). This is to ensure consecutive windows are staggered and thus visible.

Do you want to maximize IE windows created via the *Open in new window* command in IE, clicking a hyperlink in an app outside of IE, or opening a bookmark in Explorer? If so, then no, there is no native way to do that. You’ll need to search for a third-party program or shell-extension that hooks into Windows and maximizes any IE windows it detects. Alternately, you could try writing a script such as for Autohotkey to do this.

If you mean when opening IE at all, then you can create a shortcut to IE, right-click it, select Properties, then in the `Shortcut` tab, select *Maximized* in the Run field.

Answer (score 0):

It is same as Windows Explorer.

```
Win+Home: Clear all but the active window.
Win+Space: All windows become transparent so you can see through to the desktop.
Win+Up arrow: Maximize the active window.
Shift+Win+Up arrow: Maximize the active window vertically.
Win+Down arrow: Minimize the window/Restore the window if it's maximized.
Win+Left/Right arrows: Dock the window to each side of the monitor.
Shift+Win+Left/Right arrows: Move the window to the monitor on the left or right.
```

You can also interact with windows by dragging them with the mouse:

```
Drag window to the top: Maximize
Drag window left/right: Dock the window to fill half of the screen.
Shake window back/forth: Minimize everything but the current window.
Double-Click Top Window Border (edge): Maximize window vertically.
```

Check this [The Master List of New Windows 7 Shortcuts](http://lifehacker.com/5390086/the-master-list-of-new-windows-7-shortcuts)

To Minimize and Restore Current Active Window Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Space</kbd> and then <kbd>N</kbd>.

[image]

Check this image there are all character that have _ symbol are access keys. that can be used after pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> then R or M or S or N or X or C to close.

Answer (score 0):

1. Close all currently open IE windows.
2. Open a webpage. Stretch it out to full screen using the stretch arrows on IE borders. (Don't use `Maximise`)
3. Choose any link on that webpage and right-click `Open in a new window`. (Don't open in new tab)
4. Stretch that 2nd window out to the full screen. (Don't use `Maximise`)
5. Close the 1st IE window.
6. Close the 2nd resized IE window.
7. Restart IE from any shortcut to verify windows are maximised/full screen

I'm currently using Windows 8.1 with Classic Shell 4.2.0 and above procedure is what worked for me.